# how do i list a custom post type with certain genre

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink, taxonomy

What I have is a custom post type 'movies' and custom taxonomy called 'genre'.

I have added such genre like 'horror' 'family' 'action' and so forth.

What I want to do is create a hyperlink to list all the movies with a certain taxonomy.

I have tried

```
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link('movies', 'horror'); ?>">horror</a>
```

but doesn't work.

Any help be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple ...

```
<?php echo the_terms( $post->ID, 'genre', ' ', ', ', ' ' ); ?>
```